# How to run ftp-deployed exe as admin from web request?

Tags: c#, security, ftp, impersonation, runas

**Goal:** 
I periodically upload new .exe file to windows server 2003 via FTP and I want to run it manually by hitting Url of a web site on same server. Exe needs to be run under an Admin account, and not the `NETWORK SERVICE` account.

**What I achieved so far:**
I have been able to successfully run applications like notepad under the Admin account on the server via a web request by using any of these:

- PsExec,
- `.net process.Start()` with credentials supplied to `process.StartInfo` and even
- by impersonating admin and then using process.Start without credentials (http://www.f4cio.com/programmatically-impersonate-in-csharp)

**The problem:**
The above methods run my exe but Task Manager, or a call to `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` shows me that it is running under `NETWORK SERVICE`.

I suspect that this file has added security constraints because it arrived from ftp link. Checking run-as-administrator in properties of file is not an option because file will be replaced periodically and all needs to be automated. Also manual server configuration should be minimal or ideally non-existent. Code-only single-web-page solution is ideal. Editing both that asp.net web page and exe is ok. (I tried something with exe self-restarting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about this, but I suspect this has to do with you website running under the `NETWORK SERVICE` user. Whatever privileges your website-user has, the same are probably granted / passed on as you try to run your executable.

Is this server on an internal network or protected in some other way? (I should hope so!). If so, you might try changing App Pool that the website is running under to an admin account (in IIS, right click the App Pool running the site, select Advanced Settings, and look for the *Identity* setting). If I'm right, that will allow you to run your executable as an admin too.

**Be aware however, that this may increase the security risk of your setup:** Allowing your site to run under an admin account means easier access to your entire server if anyone is able to penetrate whatever security measures you have in place. Make sure access to this server is tightly limited, and preferably, that it in turn does not have access to other systems, since that would in turn make them vulnerable by extension.

Comment: My idea was to be able to include that single web/trigger page into any site. If nobody comes up with other solutions I will go with this approach where I have separate site and app pool for this trigger page. Thanks.